# Qt QML include from different directory problem

Tags: qt, qml, qt5

I have a directory structure like so for my QML files:

```
qml.qrc
main.qml
LockScreen/
  LockScreen.qml
QuickMenu/
  QuickMenu.qml
misc/
  KeyboardInput.qml
```

(there are other files I have excluded, but that's not relevant)

I have added all the above files to my qrc file, with prefixes for each directory:

```
<RCC>
    <qresource prefix="/">
        <file>main.qml</file>
        <file>qtquickcontrols2.conf</file>
        <file>MessagePopup.qml</file>
        <file>MessagePopupForm.ui.qml</file>
    </qresource>
    <qresource prefix="/LockScreen">
        <file>LockScreen/LockScreen.qml</file>
        <file>LockScreen/fingerprint.png</file>
        <file>LockScreen/fingerprint_highlighted.png</file>
    </qresource>
    <qresource prefix="/MainPages">
        <file>MainPages/LibraryPage.qml</file>
        <file>MainPages/CameraPage.qml</file>
        <file>MainPages/MessagesPage.qml</file>
        <file>MainPages/HomePage.qml</file>
        <file>MainPages/saturn.jpg</file>
    </qresource>
    <qresource prefix="/QuickMenu">
        <file>QuickMenu/QuickMenu.qml</file>
    </qresource>
    <qresource prefix="/misc">
        <file>misc/KeyboardInput.qml</file>
    </qresource>
</RCC>
```

My problem is that when I import each prefix like this

```
import "misc"
import "MainPages"
import "QuickMenu"
import "LockScreen"
```

in my main.qml, I get an error saying one of my QML objects is not a type.

```
QQmlApplicationEngine failed to load component
qrc:/main.qml:67 LockScreen is not a type
```

The strange thing is that I can access all my objects using the intellisense of QtCreator, everything seems to be imported fine until I build and run the app. Is there a way that the qrc paths are outdated or something? Or old cache files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is caused by the prefix that seems to add a level in the path, so in your case the import should be:

```
import "./LockScreen/LockScreen"
```

Although the editor loses the autocomplete and throws the warning. So it seems that the problem is with the editor who has problems interpreting the qresource alias.

---

A better option is to use an alias for the .qml file:

```
...
<qresource prefix="/LockScreen">
    <file alias="LockScreen.qml">LockScreen/LockScreen.qml</file>
    ...
```

**main.qml**

```
import "LockScreen"

LockScreen{
    // ...
}
```

**Note:** the alias must have a .qml extension otherwise Qt Creator will not recognize it correctly

Comment: The alias worked, but I am confused why the default file name is not recognized when imported? Does this mean I have to give every file in the qrc an alias?

Comment: @AndrewLoomis the prefix adds one more level to the path and it seems that Qt Creator does not recognize the properties when there are many levels. And yes, you're going to have to set an alias if you want to use prefixes, if you delete them you will not have that problem